# Ignore whitespaces in regex

Tags: c#, regex

To parse this fragment:

```
Number: 1235, Title: "Today is a good day"
```

I am using this regex:

```
^Number: (\d+?), Title: \"(.*?)\"$
```

Unfortunately now I have to deal with corrupted data, like:

```
Nu mber: 1235, Title: "Today is a good day"
Numb er: 1235, Title: "Today is a bad day"
Nu mbe r: 1235, Title: "Foo"
Number: 1235, T itle: "Bar"
Nu mber: 1235, Tit le: "Example yyy"
Number: 1235, Title: "One"
```

I have to ignore that whitespaces in `Number` and `Title` words. I cannot just remove whitespaces from my regex and input text, because I have to keep spaces in text after `Title` fragment.

This solution seems to working:

```
^\s*N\s*u\s*m\s*b\s*e\s*r\s*:\s*(\d+?)\s*,\s*T\s*i\s*t\s*l\s*e\s*:\s*\"(.*?)\"\s*$
```

But it is really unreadable. Any ideas?

Also, I would like to mention, that I don't want to match something like this

```
Age: 99, Description: "Hi"
```

Comment: You can remove all spaces from the input string

Comment: @Tal But I have to keep spaces in `Today is a good day` etc.

Comment: so remove spaces until the first quotation mark

Comment: Are you saying that you want the digits after the first colon, and the text after the second colon, and the letters "N u m b e r" and "T i t l e" don't really matter?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes. I just want to extract that data

Comment: @dafie If you use `Regex re = new Regex(@"^.*?(?<number>\d+).*?""(?<title>.*?)""$");` and `Match m = re.Match(s);` then `m.Groups["number"].Value` and `m.Groups["title"].Value` contain the values you're after, but there is no check that the line starts with anything at all, so I'm not sure if that's really what you need.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I would like to keep `Number` and `Title` somehow, because text is large, and It would match things that I dont want to match.

Comment: In which environment are you sitting? Because the best way i think is to use *lookaround*s. With them you can say: I want eveything that follows a (") and stands before another ("). And: I want everything that follows a (: ) and stands before a (,). But that won't work properly in javascript.

Comment: @JonaPaulus I can't do that, because I don't want to match: `Age: 1235, Description: "Hi"`

Comment: @dafie Then your (working) solution looks like the right way to do it. Just put a comment with it explaining that the data is sometimes corrupted with spurious spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want ungreedy qualifiers there since there's no difference between longest and shortest match; it'll be (very slightly) faster to just use `^Number: (\d+), Title: \"(.*)\"$` in your example.

If you know it'll always be just Number and Title, you can assume them:

```regex
^N[^:]+:\s+(\d+),\s+T[^:]+:\s+\"(.*)\"$
```

If you can't make that assumption, use some C# code to copy the data into a temporary variable, collapse the white space in that variable and check that first.

I don't know C#, so this sample code is likely buggy, but it should still convey my thinking:

```cs
string input = 'Nu mber: 1235, Title: "Today is a good day"';
Match match = Regex.Match(input.Replace(" ", ""), @"^Number:\d+,Title:\".*\"$");
if (match.Success) {
  match = Regex.Matches(input, @"^N[^:]+:\s+(\d+),\s+T[^:]+:\s+\"(.*)\"$")
  if (match.Success) {
    // do stuff with match[1] (the number) and match[2] (the title)
  }
}
```

This checks to see if a version of the input with its spaces removed will match the template. We can't use that because we need the spaces in the Title, but this at least verifies the formatting. Then it uses the space-tolerant regex to match, saving the two desired fields.

Comment: Thanks, I will follow your advice.